# Using Autoreleased Objects in iOS apps

Tags: objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

To return a NSArray or NSDictionary, I have seen most people use the below implementation and this is also what some books suggest. (iOS Development A Practical Approach -  )

**OPTION 1**

```
  -(NSArray*)listOfStudents{

    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMUtableArray alloc] init];

    //Add elements to the array
    //
    //
    //
    NSArray *students =  [NSArray arrayWithArray:temp];

    return students;
    }



 -(void)viewWillAppear{

    self.studentsList = [self listOfStudents];
    }
```

But can this same be done by the below way also?

OPTION 2

```
 -(NSArray*)newListOfStudents{

    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMUtableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *students = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:temp];
    [temp release];
    //Add elements to the array
    //
    //
    //


    return students;
    }


-(void)viewWillAppear{



  NSArray *array = [self newListOfStudents];
    self.studentsList = array;
    [array release];

    }
```

Assume these methods are called in the main thread itself.

Interms of memory usage , I think that the second option is good, because it does not create autoreleased objects, because they are released only at when the autorelease pool is drained.

I assume that the main autorelease pool is drained only when the app quits. So if the method in OPTION 1 is used many times ,(since they are getting called in ViewWillAppear) I think that many lists will be in autorelease pool being released only when the app quits.

So is the OPTION 2 approach the better approach?

UPDATE:

I have updated the viewWillAppear implementation for better clarity.

Comment: Given `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray` why not just return `temp` in the first code snippet.  Why waste time/memory making an immutable copy?

Comment: I thought it can possibly open up possibility for the people who use this to modify the contents since what they are internally is a mutable one..

Comment: They'd have to cast it back to `NSMutableArray`, however the *contract* of the method says "I will return an immutable array" and there are probably many ways they can mis-use the object so I don't, personally, spend any effort stopping them from breaking the system.

Comment: ok...I thought why to take any chance..

Comment: There are better things to worry about than stopping the caller from mis-using the objects you return.  Let the object look after itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* in the second example you meant to call

```
self.studentsList = [self newListOfStudents];
```

In case that `studentsList` is a `retain`ed property, this would leak now.

Also, that temp array in both examples is just useless overhead. In the second example it's plain nonsense.

The cleanest solution is

```
-(NSArray *)listOfStudents {
   NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];
   // Add things to array
   return list;
}
```

Two more advices:

1) you might run the static analyzer over your code, which will point to memory issues.
2) if you feel more confident with memory management, switch over to ARC.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. The "new" approach gives you better control of when it will be released, but then, this will rarely ever matter. Generally, the autoreleased version is the most common pattern. I cannot recommend ARC enough, though - it makes code simpler, and often better performing as well.

Comment: Does it cost us in memory if  autoreleased version is used instead of new version , since autoreleased objects will be released only when autorlease pool will be drained?

Comment: Autoreleased objects may stick a bit longer around than necessary, but it will rarely hurt. A typical exception is using autoreleased objects in a tight loop, but one can use separate autorelease pools here. Many system libraries work a lot with autoreleased objects, too.